# Global guards/filters/interceptors does not trigger during e2e testing, GRPC

Tags: nestjs

I'm having issues with global guards, interceptors and filters that does work during runtime but does not work during e2e testing.

Here's an example of a guard setup. The issue is the same for all middleware like items, they do not trigger unless I specified them locally for each controller etc.

My top module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: JWT_PASS,
      global: true,
    }),
    BoothModule,
    SessionTypeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthenticationGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

A guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  private readonly log = new Logger('AuthenticationGuard');

  constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
     console.log('triggered?!');
     ....
     return true;
  }
```

The console log works, the tests fails as the guard logic fails.

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ClientsModule.register([
          {
            name: '<name>',
            transport: Transport.GRPC,
            options: {
              url: 'localhost:5001',
              package: '<package>',
              protoPath: '<path>',
              credentials: GRPC.ChannelCredentials.createInsecure(),
            },
          },
        ]),
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ExceptionInterceptor());
    app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
      transport: Transport.GRPC,
      options: {
        url: 'localhost:5001',
        package: SPEEDPHOTO_PACKAGE_NAME,
        protoPath: BOOTH_PROTO,
      },
    });

    await app.startAllMicroservices();

    await app.init();

    const clientGrpc: ClientGrpc = app
      .getMicroservices()[0]
      .get(BOOTH_SERVICE_NAME);
    client = clientGrpc.getService<BoothServiceClient>(BOOTH_SERVICE_NAME);
  });
```

It only fails during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the `TestingModule.createNestApplication()` creates an HTTP base application, and when that's the case, for RPC applications to make use of the globally bound enhancers, you have to pass the option [`{ inheritAppConfig: true }`](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#sharing-configuration) as a second parameter of `connectMicroservice()`

Comment: It works! 

Thank you, I totally missed that 